# Whether sequencing of column is possible during a BULK insert in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Whether sequencing of column is possible during a **BULK insert** in oracle

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, can you please be a little more specific in your question.

Comment: @vishad: We use bulk insert statement to insert to temp table, We need to produce custom sequence for a column in it, So Is sequencing of column is possible during a bulk insert?

Comment: Still not much sure about your requirement, but yes you can use Oracle sequences while doing Bulk Insert in Oracle Temp tables or collection.
Think, will be better if you can provide an example of what are your inputs and what are your desired outputs.